# census questionnaire

Tags: confidence-interval

if you administered a census questionnaire to an entire group of interest ("population") and got a 68% response rate. Is it wrong to calculate confidence intervals for the medians of the data subsets? The data subsets contain outliers and medians were calculated. Tx!

Comment: It seems that you are you are using two unregistered accounts. Please, follow the [instructions on our help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) to merge them and don't forget to register your account once and for all.

Comment: I've marked this as a possible duplicate (as well as a certain duplicate of another, now closed question).  The thing that might make it different is that you are now asking specifically about medians.  If this is a question about medians I think it is ok to stand; if it is a repeat of the more general question about confidence intervals it is a duplicate.  However, I can't think of any way it would be wrong to calculate confidence intervals for the medians other than because of the missing data problems discussed in the possible duplicate.